# Can I combine key-chord-mode with evil-define-key?

Tags: key-bindings, evil, key-chord-mode

I like to use `evil-define-key` like so:

```
(evil-define-key 'normal projectile-mode-map
  (kbd "M-o") 'projectile-switch-to-buffer)
```

This is great because I can make bindings for both an emacs mode and an evil state at the same time.

Unfortunately though I cannot figure out how to integrate this style, with [key-chord-mode](https://github.com/emacsorphanage/key-chord).

I thought I had found the solution with the following, but this is a different kind of key-chord than the ones provided by `key-chord-mode`.

```
(evil-define-key 'normal projectile-mode-map
   (kbd "<key-chord> po") 'projectile-switch-to-buffer
```

Is there a way to essentially say the following?:

```
(evil-define-key 'normal projectile-mode-map
   (key-chord-define "po") 'projectile-switch-to-buffer))
```

Comment: You almost have the solution. If you look more closely at [`key-chord-define`](https://github.com/emacsorphanage/key-chord/blob/7f7fd7c5bd2b996fa054779357e1566f7989e07d/key-chord.el#L124-L142) you note that you just need to define the key sequence additionally with reversed sequence of letters. `(evil-define-key 'normal projectile-mode-map (kbd "<key-chord> op") 'projectile-switch-to-buffer)`.

Comment: You could use [general.el](https://github.com/noctuid/general.el), a great wrapper for bindings: `(general-define-key :keymaps 'projectile-mode-map :states 'insert (general-chord "po") 'projectile-switch-to-buffer (general-chord "op") 'projectile-switch-to-buffer)`. Make sure you enable `key-chord-mode` to make it work.